# MailComposeViewController Error: unexpectedly found nil

Tags: swift, null, runtime-error, optional-values

I'm trying to save the email and time of an email i sent, to a table view. The emails send fine, but I get this error (Error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value) whenever I click the send button. I'm not sure where is the error in my code.

The code for the send button:

```
//SentEmails Array
var sentEmails = [emailObject]()

//Default email
var sentEmailTo = "email@email.com"

//Dismiss Buttons for Mail Composer
func mailComposeController(controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error:NSError?) {

    //Check for errors
   if let error = error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    switch result {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        print("Mail Cancelled")
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        print("Mail Saved")
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:

     //Save information to tableview
        let emailSent = emailObject(sentTo: sentEmailTo, timeSent: NSDate())
        sentEmails.append(emailSent)
        tableView.reloadData()

        print("Mail Sent")

    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        print("Mail sent failure: \(error)")
    default:
        break
    }

    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

My cell code:

```
//Cell Configuration
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let row = indexPath.row

    let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
    dateFormat.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    cell.textLabel?.text = sentEmails[row].sentTo
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormat.stringFromDate(sentEmails[row].timeSent)



    return cell
}
```

The error:

[image]

*Didn't know I could do this lol, here's the error detail:

[image]

Comment: What line does the debugger point to when it crashes?

Comment: @pbush25 it doesn't point to anything, but a page, ill post it in a second.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of where it points in your ViewController? When same happens again, open ViewController class and make a screenshot there

Comment: That's the problem.. there's nothing there. That page is the only thing I get back from the error.

Comment: When I take this out from the mailComposeController: let emailSent = emailObject(sentTo: sentEmailTo, timeSent: NSDate())
            sentEmails.append(emailSent)
            tableView.reloadData() ... everything works fine, but i can't populate the table view. That's why im guessing the error is there or in the table view, im not sure.

Comment: tableView is nil is it all working when you put some dummy info into sentEmails?

Comment: Perhaps try commenting out: code cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormat.stringFromDate(sentEmails[row].timeSent) and see if you get a non crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the tableView connected in interface builder like this?  You need to define your datasource, delegate and outlets for the table if not (the "Gratitude Stream" bits are from my example but yours will be from your own view controller).
[image]

Comment: I don't have reference outlet connected, but when i try it wont connect to the tableView but the view directly... i open my app and the screen is black

Comment: Great - let me know what the issue was!

Comment: my tableView IBOutlet wasn't connected in the view controller

Comment: It's the thing that always bites me ;) -  If helpful could you mark mine answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

When the crash happens, you can press on the row with `1`, 
[image]

and it will display more information on where the crash happened (in ViewController file). Can you post a screenshot of that?

Sorry I can't post an image as a comment to the question. Will edit the answer once we know more.

Comment: There, i posted the image.

Comment: It's most likely that tableView is nil at that point. Can you check that?

Comment: How can I check that? It's empty, i haven't added anything to it.

Comment: When you are on a crash breakpoint, type "po tableView" into the console and it will print the contents of the variable.

Comment: I got this error back: Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
expression produced error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1001e2588).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: I fixed it!! it was really dumb (of course)... My tableView outlet wasn't connected. It works fine now. Thank you for your help. Also, for the neat tricks looking for the error :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Debugger console is a really powerful tool for debugging